# Too Many Redirects on 3G Only

Tags: php, android, redirect, mobile

I have a very wierd "Too Many Redirects" error being reported on an HTC mobile phone.

My site is simple, using a javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = "http://mobile.mydomain.com";
  }
</script>
```

The script works fine on iphone and blackberry. The script also works fine with HTC phone when the phone is connected via WIFI. However when the HTC device is connected via 3G it reports error "Too Mnay Redirects". (I've tested the HTC on two different networks).

Does anyone have any ideas?

p.s. I tried a number of redirect methods (inclusing a PHP 301 header readirect).

Comment: You don't have the redirect script also on the mobile.mydomain.com website do you?

Comment: No, I've even tried to to reduce the code on both the landing page and the redirected page to the following:
    <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
  
 <meta charset="utf-8" />       
        <title>Welcome to ANS Security</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Show This</p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Do you have the same problem on the desktop when resizing the window to < 800px?

Comment: Absolutely no problem on desktop, in fact if I change JS to >=800 the desktop redirects correctly to the mobile site. Seems only a problem when using android browser via 3g, tried it on two android devices (very strange)